# Do i need to insert spring-core module explicitly?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I implemented a spring-webmvc and hibernate project. but I did not include spring-core in my pom.xml file. but my code is working and dependency injection also working.

my doubts are

1. how spring-webmvc and spring-orm are working without spring-core?
2. should I import spring-core in my project to avoid future problems?

here is my dependencies (pom.xml)

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate Core -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
    <!-- JSTL Dependency -->
    <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
    <!-- JSP Dependency -->
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both spring-webmvc and spring-orm depend on spring core so you don't have to add this dependency explicitly.
You can check all dependencies of spring-webmvc here: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/spring-webmvc.gradle

and spring-orm dependencies here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/spring-orm.gradle

Also you could use
 `mvn dependency:tree`
command to check all dependencies without looking in source code

Comment: it's great doubt clear... thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

`spring-webmvc`, as well as `spring-orm` (and pretty much any other `spring-XYZ` module) depends on `spring-core`, so it's a loaded as a transitive dependency. See all of the dependencies here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.1.5.RELEASE